# can't set background color ttk python os x using styles

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, tkinter, ttk

With this code fragment, I would expect the label to have a background color red.
def createWidgets(self):

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Red.TLabel", foreground="green", background="red")

    self.label1 = ttk.Label(textvariable=self.numberArray[0][0],style="Red.TLabel")
    self.label1.pack()
```

I get the green foreground color but I can't change the background color.
This is on OS X. I'm using ActiveState's tcl and python. The same problem occurs with Python 3.2 and 2.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You'll sometimes try to change an option that is supposed to exist according to element options, but it will have no effect. **As an example, you can't modify the background color of a button in the "aqua" theme used by Mac OS X.** While there are valid reasons for these cases, at the moment its not easy to discover them, which can make experimenting frustrating at times.

Taken from this tutorial http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html