# Tkk: custom style doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to learn how to create a custom ttk style by following this documentition: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html

Here is the code:

```
    self.style = ttk.Style()
    self.style.configure("ciao.TLabel", bg="red")
    poplabel = ttk.Label(self.root, text="ciao", style="ciao.TLabel")
    poplabel.place(x=0, y=530)
```

The problem is that the label style remains the default one and not the "ciao.TLabel".

Comment: What OS are you using? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723850) might help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "bg" does not exist on ttk. Only "background" does, in fact

```
self.style.configure("ciao.TLabel", background="red")
```

works.

Comment: Congratulations to finding the answer to your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering the problem because background of a `ttk.Label` is not customised from changing style but by changing the background option in `w = ttk.Label(parent, option=value, ...)`.

To change background colour from an existing colour, you need to do:
`poplabel.configure(background='red')` or `poplabel[background]='red'`.

To change background of default while creating the ttk.label, type:
`poplabel = ttk.Label(self.root, text="ciao", background="red")`

**Update:** My bad, you can change the background as mentioned above and also by using style. L'ultimo is correct. :)